# Angular 8 select no preselected option

Tags: angular8, html-select

Is there a way to remove the preselected option in `<select>` element, like it happens with `mat-select`?
I mean that I don't want the first element of the array to be preselected in the element, but without adding an "empty" entry. I want something like this:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible with native select?

Answer (score 0):

just include another option at the top:

```
 <mat-option>None</mat-option>
```